# How to insert a custom type with map<text, boolean> field using cqlsh in Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cqlsh

I am getting an error like this:

```
field is not of type frozen<map<text, boolean>>
```

Any example for inserting a custom type object in which a filed is of type `frozen<map<text, boolean>>`?

Any idea how to do this with nodejs cassandra-driver?

**UPDATE**

Tried as @Olivier Michallat mentioned. But my answer is as below. Any idea why it comes like this instead of a josn?

```
cqlsh:test> create type t(m map<text, boolean>);
cqlsh:test> create table foo(k int primary key, v frozen<t>);
cqlsh:test> insert into foo(k,v) values (1, {m: {'foo': true}});
cqlsh:test> select * from foo;

 k | v
---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | \x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03foo\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01

(1 rows)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks @Olivier Michallat, the latest cqlsh gave me the expected results.

```
amt@amt-db:~$ docker run -it --rm --link cass1:cass poklet/cassandra cqlsh cass
Connected to Test Cluster at cass:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.5 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use test;
cqlsh:test> create type setting(timeout timestamp, capabilities map<text, boolean>);
cqlsh:test> create table app(id uuid primary key, name text, defaultSetting frozen<setting>);
cqlsh:test> insert into app(id, name, defaultSetting) values (7031d49e-70cf-450d-90d8-178fa97c5e67, 'Test Cassandra', {timeout: 30, capabilities: {'read': true, 'write': false, 'delete': false}});
cqlsh:test> select * from app;

 id                                   | defaultsetting                                                                                       | name
--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 7031d49e-70cf-450d-90d8-178fa97c5e67 | {timeout: '1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000', capabilities: {'delete': False, 'read': True, 'write': False}} | Test Cassandra

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test>
```

I updated my node version to "v0.12.4". But the nodejs cassandra-driver does not give me expected response.

```
//filename: udt.js
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

var options = {
    contactPoints: ["192.168.2.203"],
    keyspace: "test",
    encoding: {
        map: Map,
        set: Set
    }
};
var client = new cassandra.Client(options);

client.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.info("connect err", err);
        return;
    }
    var query = 'select * from app';
    client.execute(query, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.info("query err", err);
            return;
        }
        console.info(result.rows);
    });
});
```

See the result

```
manu@kochi:~/app/test$ node udt.js 
[ { id: Uuid: 7031d49e-70cf-450d-90d8-178fa97c5e67,
    defaultsetting: 
     { timeout: Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
       capabilities: {} },
    name: 'Test Cassandra' } ]
```

@BryceAtNetwork23 any idea why 'capabilities' are not shown using node cassandra-driver?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example in cqlsh. The column holding the user type must be marked `frozen` (which indicates that Cassandra serializes it as a single value):

```
cqlsh:test> create type t(m map<text, boolean>);
cqlsh:test> create table foo(k int primary key, v frozen<t>);
cqlsh:test> insert into foo(k,v) values (1, {m: {'foo': true}});
cqlsh:test> select * from foo;

 k | v
---+--------------------
 1 | {m: {'foo': True}}

(1 rows)
```

Comment: <!---
See my result is like below
cqlsh:test> select * from foo;

 k | v
---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | \x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03foo\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01

(1 rows)
-->

Comment: Which version of cqlsh are you using? It looks like it's an old version that does not display custom types well. What does it say when you connect initially? (something like `Connected to v210 at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]`)

Comment: C:\Users\Useer>python C:\python27_x64\Scripts\cqlsh 192.168.2.203
Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.2.203:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.5 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take the second part of your question.

> Any idea how to do this with nodejs cassandra-driver?

Based on what I'm seeing in the [DataStax node.js driver documentation on collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.2/features/datatypes/collections/#map), you should use Javascript objects as a map value (using similar naming conventions to what Oliver has indicated):

```
var key = 1;
var m = {
   foo: true
};
var query = 'UPDATE foo SET v = ? WHERE k = ?';
client.execute(query, [m, key], { prepare: true}, callback);
```

Comment: the link is dead already, I found [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.2/features/datatypes/collections/#map) helpful

Comment: @Scaramouche Edit made.  Thanks for posting the new link!